# Intermittent server error when submitting forms using Django

Tags: django, google-app-engine, https, web-applications

I am getting the following 500 server error when I deploy my Django web application to google app engine:

```
Error server error the server encountered an error and could not complete your request please try again in 30 seconds
```

Simply refreshing the page solves this issue and renders the page. However, this isn't ideal and I want the page to load correctly the first time tried. This error does not occur on my localhost, it only occurs on the [deployed site](https://jetstreamjet.com/) and typically during form submissions and rendering detail pages.

I've researched the HTTP status codes in Django extensively from [their documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/error-reporting/). It does not matter if the app is set in DEBUG mode or not. The same error appears. This is happening for both GET and POST requests. I have also tried to use a try-except block to retry the request multiple times before accepting failure.

My configuration:

- Django: 3.2.9
- Browser: Chrome 98.0.4758.80

Comment: What does the log file say for this error?

Comment: As @NoCommandLine mentioned is there some more information available for this error in logs? And also, could you confirm if you have tried with DEBUG = TRUE?

Answer (score 0):

Simply needed to upgrade my google app engine tier to a more professional level. Nothing was wrong, I just outgrew my tier and it just needed more computing power.